# Initialize Pinia store with a type

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, pinia

Disclaimer: I am an JS beginner

I am synchronizing an object with pinia store and a python REST API. I Want to declare a type only once and not have to mirror it in the store.

```js
export const useTicketStore = defineStore('ticket', {
  state: () => ({
    id: null,
    status: "",
    subject: "",
    email: "",
    department: null,
    ticketType: nulll,
  }),
  actions: {
    save() {
      const action = this.id ? axios.patch : axios.post
      const url = this.id ? `/api/tickets/${this.id}` : "/api/tickets"
      action(url, this).then((response) => {
        this.$patch(response.data)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Throughout my app I use an type declaration for consistancy:

```js
interface Ticket {
    id: number | null,
    status: string,
    subject: string,
    email: string,
    department: number | null,
    ticketType: number | null,
}
```

What I would like to do is something like this

```js
export const useTicketStore = defineStore('ticket', {
  state: () => ({
    ...Ticket
  }),
  actions: {
...
})
```

using the example above results in an strange error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/types/ticket.ts' does not provide an export named 'Ticket'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are encoutring tells that the file from where you try to import `Ticket` does not have a default export so if you didn't define a default export you have to import this way:

```js
import {Ticket} from '...'; // with curly brackets
```

about what you want to achieve, the function is returning an object (key-value), it may be of type `Ticket` but you cannot replace it with `Ticket` because `Ticket` is a type, not an object. 
you still can define a return type for the function, but this will not avoid specifying the values of the returned object:

```js
state: (): Ticket => ({
  id: null,
  status: "",
  subject: "",
  email: "",
  department: null,
  ticketType: null,
})
```

Comment: `export { Ticket }` I wrote at the end of my type declaration. `import { Ticket } from '@/types/ticket' ` and this for import, thta why my error was strange